My AWS Serverless.template keeps getting over-written
I'm working in VS2022 with the AWS Toolkit installed.
On one particular project the serverless.template file is overwritten after I "Publish to AWS Lambda".  All of my functions in the script contained in serverless.template are deleted to the default shown below.  My file is reduced from 145 lines to 47 lines.  I have to keep all of my changes in a different file and paste them in every time I want to deploy.
I copied to a new file "serverless2.template" and it's doing the same thing.
Has anyone got a fix for this glitch?
This is what it gets reset back to:..
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "TCR Manager API This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.5.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "TcrManagerLambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
          }
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
        ],
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "lambdaPolicyAllowSecretsManager",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "Resource": "*"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}

